# image default source not covering whole image view react native

Tags: react-native, image

I want to give a placeholder image until the original image is loaded from the network so iam using the default source prop of the image but it is not displayed correctly I want it to cover the whole image view but it's not

[image]

the original image after being loaded from the network
[image]

my code

```
   <Image
            source={{ URI: `${BASE_URL}/file_uploads/${image}` }}
            defaultSource={require('./g-design.png')}
            resizeMode='cover'
            style={{ height: 120, width: 122, borderRadius: 70}} />
```

placeholder image = 252 x 249

note: I don't want to use any hook or other imageview

Comment: If you are importing Image from react-native,  put "resizeMode" in style like it:-
style={{ height: 120, width: 122, borderRadius: 70, resizeMode:"cover"}}

Comment: didn't work i tried it

Comment: same problem ^^^